# Bind Enum Text based on the value to WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, enums, webgrid

I have been working on Binding various Student Data in WebGrid. Data contains Enum value, so after binding the Webgrid i get value in output but i want to show respective Enum Text for that Value.
Below is my Enum present in MVCDemo.Common.Enum namespace

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Display(Name = "Male")]
    Male = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Female")]
    Female = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Other")]
    Other = 3
}
```

Here goes my WebGrid

```
var AdminGrid = new WebGrid(source: lstStudent, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, canSort: true, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow");

            @AdminGrid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "table table-bordered  table-hover  table-condensed",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
                selectedRowStyle: "selectRow",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                rowStyle: "webGridDataRow",
                columns: AdminGrid.Columns(              
                    AdminGrid.Column("Firstname", "First Name"),
                    AdminGrid.Column("Email", "Email"),
                    AdminGrid.Column("Gender", "Gender"),
                    AdminGrid.Column("IdRole", "Role")))
```

My problem is Gender is of Enum type but in output it display either 1, 2 or 3, but instead i want to show Male, Female, Other based on the Value.

Comment: Solved this issue, in case if anyone encounter this kind of issue can ask for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.Column("Gender", "Gender",format: (item) => item.Gender == 1 ? 
Enum.Gender.Male : item.Gender == 2 ? Enum.Gender.Female : Enum.Gender.Other),
```

Here is

```
1 is Male,
2 is Female,
3 is Other
```

try it it will work 100%.